# Load Divs Asynchronously in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a page I want to load that has sections that are making API calls. I don't the page to wait to load until those are done. I would like the page to load and then the other sections to appear after they are finished.

Right now, this is what I have but it's not getting the results I want and even with this it's still waiting for a lot to process and not loading the page first, even though it seems like it should be.

```
<script>
    $(window).load(function(){
        $(".my-div").append('<%= my_function %>');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried `$(document).ready()`?

Answer (score 0):

**Assets**

Don't use `erb` code in your asset pipeline

Including that code in your layout or view will be okay, but if you're including in `app/assets/javascripts/any_file.js`, it won't work

`ERB` code can only be processed by `js` in `views` folders (mainly because of the precompile process of the `asset` pipeline)

---

**Appending**

As pointed out in the comments, you'd be better waiting until the `document` has loaded, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //your code
});
```

However, if you're using turbolinks, you'd be better using something like this:

```
var load = function() {
    //append code here
};

$(document).ready(load);
$(document).on('page:load', load);
```

---

**Functionality**

Curiously, you've omitted one of the most important aspects of your code -- how you're retrieving the data. If you can reply with your asynchronous function, it will be a great help!

Comment: I just had that javascript inside my view and was getting the data by calling a private helper method in my controller, but that's probably not the best way to do things. I'm open to any tips. Would love it if you could point me in the right direction for best practice on this sort of thing. Thanks.